# what is the use of new keyword

Tags: c#

Is it only used to create reference of object's?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Sample pf = new Sample();
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+new+in+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=what+is+new+keyword+in+c%23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `new` can be used to create a *new* instance of a `Type`, or to hide *inherited member* in *derived class* or as a *generic type constraint*. Check this [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4.aspx) MSDN doc.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say new "references" but "instances", yes. All you need to know about `new` you find on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx).